# Operation Aborted in IE 7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have Operation Aborted each time I Refresh my website's page.
I read the article of MSFT about this issue, and I dont have that case.

I have a div inside the body that appends a script to the head
and the head modifies all the body elements...

What can cause this??

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was `<span dir="" ...>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to install activex control.

If you enable it ,automatically promt to install activex.